# Tab Key Navigation for Child Controls in Silverlight Grid

Tags: silverlight, silverlight-4.0

I am using silverlight grid. I have two columns.One is text column.Another one is template column.Basically i am achieving input form using grid.

```
Label    Input control
Username TextBox control
Password PasswordBox control 
Enabled  CheckBox control
and so on
```

label and input controls are resolved at runtime.Now if you click tab key,focus goes to cell.Instead of this behavior, I want to make the control to get focus when tab key is pressed.

Thanks in Advance

Answer (score 1):

in silverlight by default tab sequence is one by one control which set in grid,if you want to change tab sequence then you can set `tabindex` in each control